# Facebook Meta Tag og:image PHP condition

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I used that PHP code for og:image meta tag but it doesn't work, it's right but it doesn't call the right source of the image.

```
<?php JFactory::getDocument(); $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.sell4masari.com/images/com_adsmanager/ads/<?php.$img->image?>" />');?>
```

So I will appreciate any help from anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting the `<?php` tags inside the quotes, so it is not being processed:

```
content="[...]/ads/<?php.$img->image?>" />');
```

You need to build the string through concatenation, like so:

```
<?php JFactory::getDocument(); $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.sell4masari.com/images/com_adsmanager/ads/' . $img->image . '" />');?>
```

Comment: Thank you Tordek for your reply but it doesn't work and when i debug i got the content like this `content="http://www.sell4masari.com/images/com_adsmanager/ads/"` there is no a source for the image.

Comment: Does $img exist and does $img->image have the right value?

Comment: Then I'm sorry, I don't see what could be failing; the syntax is correct and if the variables exist they should be concatenated correctly...

Comment: Ok don't worry, Thank you anyway.